# xeditable drop down's selected value is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, x-editable

I'm using [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) module.So my question is how can I get the drop down's change value ? At this moment it's not working.Please check the below plunk.Thanks in advance.

```
 <div ng-controller="Ctrl" style="margin: 50px">
      <a href="#" editable-select="user.status" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses" e-ng-change="myAlert(user.status)">
        {{ showStatus() }}
      </a>
      <br><br>
      debug: {{ user | json }}
    </div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bqB69Z)

**EDIT**

I need to hide the left hand text box (`Name's column`) according to the value of drop down (when user selects it).Could you tell me how to do that ?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/78/)**

**EDIT 2 :**

[image]

Comment: Seems to save fine when you click the save button. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: The problem you're going to have there is that since there is a table structure being used, you'd somehow have to hide each <td> element. I'd use a ng-hide on the `<td>` containing `<span editable-text="user.name" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)">` as well as the header cell.

Comment: @KreepN Actually it is on the same column side by side.Please see the Edit 2.

Comment: @KreepN If you can please simulate it on the above jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example forked from your fiddle, change the dropdown to 1:

http://jsfiddle.net/crv2vst5/

```
$scope.Selected = 0;
$scope.Hidden = false;

$scope.HideNameColumn = function(val) {

    if(parseInt(val) == 1){        
        $scope.Hidden = true; 
    }
    else{             
        $scope.Hidden = false;
    }       
}
```

EDIT:

Done : http://jsfiddle.net/Lw7h956h/

**Final :**

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2h1rh1vc/)

Comment: Could you do it within the row ? As I mentioned on Edit 2.In other words particular row's text box.

Comment: @Sampath Perhaps. Let's see.

Comment: I have pressed the edit button.Then what will happen when I select a `0 or 1`. Which text box will hide ?

Comment: @Sampath Whatever row you select the 1 on, the first column's data will hide.

Comment: Did you use `$scope.HideNameColumn` somewhere within the UI ? I couldn't see that on `ng-change` event ?

Comment: I simplified the logic and removed it's usage. The dropdown is what directly toggles the hidden property. No method needed.

Comment: Can I have latest JsFiddle ?

Comment: Actually If you can do it by using `ng-change`,That is what I need.B'cos on my scenario it's not T/F.

Comment: I would like to know about how to do it by using `ng-change` ?

Comment: I'm aware. You have to give me a few minutes to make the change. http://jsfiddle.net/2h1rh1vc/

Comment: Thank a lot my FRIEND.It's working.Have a Great Day Ahead :)